# display lookup data as text in asp.net gridview with microsoft access backend

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

i am facing a boring issue when i have to present lookup table data (with MS Access backend) in an ASP.net page

the main table **Employees** that the asp.net page will show its data includes one field **main.gender** with type "Integer" which is linked to the lookup table **gender**

if the table is linked to gridview, then the field in question will display

"1" or "2"

i need to display

"male" and "female"

i figured out two ways to solve this issue but i dont think any of them is the best thing to do

first way:

-convert the gridview field **gender** to template field, replace the label in edit template with dropdownlist linked to the lookup table and display gender as text
-make the DDL enabled=false to be "read only"
-problem is that DDL show dimmed text

second way:

to make a select query replacing Employee.gender(integer) with gender.gender(text)
this way is MUCH SLOWER in data retrieval

could anyone please help me find a way to display text with a more "professional" way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mokokamello

try use join in the asp.net datasource select command, below is how it looks like in pseudocode

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/database.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.NameEmployee, Gender.Gender FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Gender ON Table1.gender = Gender.ID">
                    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

it need no code behind, no dropdown lists, no database embedded queries and it is significantly faster that the ways you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Enum with your Data:

```
protected enum MyEnum
{
 male = 1,
 female = 2
}
```

And then use something like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
  <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyName" />
   //Add one column for your each property you want to display

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <%# (MyEnum)Eval("Gender") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: thanks dima, but this will be hard coded. do you have another more "dynamic" solution, by the way i voted up for you since you always answer my questions :)

Comment: For more dynamic, you can retrieve gender table as List<gender> genders and then use LinQ, add to codebehind method GetGenderString(int genderId){ return genders.Where(x => x.Id == genderId).select(x => x.Name } and then use somethink like this in html part <ItemTemplate> <%# GeGenderString(Eval("Gender")) %></ItemTemplate>. Is it dynamic enough? ))

Comment: it is, thanks a lot Dima, one more question--> how can i use LinQ with MS access back end, i receive a "provider" error